How to map array database type to kotlin
I have this entity
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
class Foo(
    @Column(name = "bar_ids", columnDefinition = "uuid[]")
    val barIds: Array<UUID>,
) {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long = 0
}

which gives me

'Basic' attribute type should not be 'UUID[]'

How to define an array datatype?

JPA does not support arrays in the Java side out of the box, even though the DB might support them. The solution is probably simple, provide an implementation of the AttributeConverter that converts between java.sql.Array DB objects to your desired UUID[].

@NikosParaskevopoulos I think I found a solution, see my answer

Yeap, if you are using Hibernate and don't mind the portability its a good idea. (It's not portable indeed, but I don't really mind) Why don't you mark your answer as accepted too?

@NikosParaskevopoulos because 'You can accept your own answer tomorrow'. What do you mean with portability?

(portability: the @Type is Hibernate-specific, so it wouldn't work in say EclipseLink; just a minor comment)

I think, this is the way to go

import io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.array.EnumArrayType
import io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.array.internal.AbstractArrayType

@Type(
      value = EnumArrayType::class,
      parameters = [Parameter(name = AbstractArrayType.SQL_ARRAY_TYPE, value = "uuid")]
    )
    @Column(name = "bar_ids", columnDefinition = "uuid[]")
    val barIds: List<UUID>,


